# AVL tree insert function

Tags: c, data-structures, avl-tree

```
AvlTree
Insert( ElementType X, AvlTree T)
{
  1   if( T == NULL)
  2  {
  3     /* Create and return a one-onde tree */
  4      T = malloc( sizeof( struct AvlNode ) );
  5      if( T == NULL )
  6          FatalError( "Out of space!!!");
  7      else
  8     {
  9         T->Element = X; T->Height = 0;
 10         T->Left = T->Right = NULL;
 11       }
 12   }
 13   else
 14   if( X < T->Element )
 15   {
 16       T->left = Insert(x, T->left );
 17       if( Height( T->left ) - Height( T->Right ) == 2 )
 18           if( X < T->Left->Element )
 19               T = SingleRotatewithLeft( T );
 20           else
 21               T = DoubleRotateWithLeft( T );
 22    }
 23    else
 24    if( X > T->Element )
 25   {
 26        T->Right = Insert( X, T->Right );
 27        if( Height( T->Right ) - Height( T->Left ) == 2 )
 28            if( X > T->Right->Element )
 29                T = SingleRotateWithRight( T );
 30            else
 31                T = DoubleRotateWithRight( T );
 32    }
 33    /* Else X is in the tree already; we'll do nothing */
 34    T->Height = Max( Height( T->Left ), Height( T->Right ) ) + 1;
 35    return T;
}
```

why X isn't equal to `T->left->Element`, 
and how can X compare with `T->left->Element`
the X should be assign to the `T->left-Element`(when the `T->left = NULL`)

Comment: When posting code, please don't include line-numbers. Instead mark specific lines with comments.

Comment: Please identify which part(s) of the code you are asking about.

Comment: @Scott Hunter just like the line 18, the X isn't equal to `T->left->Element`?

Answer (score 0):

After line 18, `X` has been inserted into `T->Left`, but it may not (necessarily) be at the top of that tree.